# Convert string to int C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, int, typeconverter

I have below code.

```
string inputStringg = "‪120000";
int numValuee = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Some Sample Name : " + numValuee.ToString());
try
{
    numValuee = Int32.Parse(inputStringg); // throws exception
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
Console.WriteLine("Some Sample Name : " + numValuee.ToString());

string inputString1 = "120000";
int numValue1 = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Some Sample Name : " + numValue1.ToString());
try
{
    numValue1 = Int32.Parse(inputString1); // no exception here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}

Console.WriteLine("Some Sample Name : " + numValue1.ToString());
```

Here `numValuee = Int32.Parse(inputStringg);`

throws exception `Input string was not in a correct format.`

and this `numValue1 = Int32.Parse(inputString1);` does not throw exception.

I know it's a silly question but don't know what's happening.

Someone, please guide me.thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first string contains an invisible character, [U+202A](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202a/index.htm) - "left to right embedding". You should work out why you've got that in your string, and fix it.

Comment: To help spot these kinds of issues, I often check the length of the string involved - `Console.WriteLine(inputStringg.Length);`

Comment: `string codes = string.Join(" ", inputStringg.Select(c => ((int) c).ToString("x4"))); Debug.Write(codes);` and you'll see `202a 0031 0032 0030 0030 0030 0030`

Comment: and instead of `int numValue1 = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Some Sample Name : " + numValue1.ToString());
try
{
    numValue1 = Int32.Parse(inputString1);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}` you can just do: `int numValue1 = 0; int.TryParse( inputString1, out numValue1 );`

Comment: @mjwills i got proper length value.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I tried with TryParse but same issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet both strings are same.

Comment: No they're not. I copied each of them from your question into http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx#explorer and saw the difference. Look at the length of each, and you should see the difference. Now if you're saying that the strings in your actual code don't match the ones in your question, that makes it very hard to help you.

Comment: try to manually type this number to your `string inputStringg = "‪120000";` and try again. it working on my side well

Comment: Thanks a lot all... it saved me.

Comment: `i got proper length value.` No you didn't. It would have been one higher than what it should have been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you copy the first string from HTML page? I guess the string that you copied has hidden characters (Unicode), which can be viewed in Word. However, if you are really after making the try parse work, I can suggest you to do the following:

```
string inputStringg = "‪120000";
inputStringg = new string(inputStringg.Where(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToArray());
int numvalue;
numvalue = int.Parse( inputStringg );
System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine( "" + numvalue );
```

Unicode strings might contain control characters and or hidden characters, so before parsing we need to pre-process the string accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same, your first string contains an invisible character as [@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52515090/2946329) already mentioned. This is the underlying IL, by [Ildasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler):

```
     // Code size       142 (0x8e)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] string inputStringg,
           [1] int32 numValuee,
           [2] string inputString1,
           [3] int32 numValue1,
           [4] class [mscorlib]System.Exception ex,
           [5] class [mscorlib]System.Exception V_5)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      bytearray (2A 20 31 00 32 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 30 00 )       // * 1.2.0.0.0.0.
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0008:  stloc.1
  IL_0009:  ldstr      "Some Sample Name : "
  IL_000e:  ldloca.s   numValuee
  IL_0010:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
  IL_0015:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string)
  IL_001a:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_001f:  nop
  .try
  {
    IL_0020:  nop
    IL_0021:  ldloc.0
    IL_0022:  call       int32 [mscorlib]System.Int32::Parse(string)
    IL_0027:  stloc.1
    IL_0028:  nop
    IL_0029:  leave.s    IL_0030
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
  {
    IL_002b:  stloc.s    ex
    IL_002d:  nop
    IL_002e:  rethrow
  }  // end handler
  IL_0030:  ldstr      "Some Sample Name : "
  IL_0035:  ldloca.s   numValuee
  IL_0037:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
  IL_003c:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string)
  IL_0041:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0046:  nop
  IL_0047:  ldstr      "120000"
  IL_004c:  stloc.2
  IL_004d:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_004e:  stloc.3
  IL_004f:  ldstr      "Some Sample Name : "
  IL_0054:  ldloca.s   numValue1
  IL_0056:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
  IL_005b:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string)
  IL_0060:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_0065:  nop
  .try
  {
    IL_0066:  nop
    IL_0067:  ldloc.2
    IL_0068:  call       int32 [mscorlib]System.Int32::Parse(string)
    IL_006d:  stloc.3
    IL_006e:  nop
    IL_006f:  leave.s    IL_0076
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
  {
    IL_0071:  stloc.s    V_5
    IL_0073:  nop
    IL_0074:  rethrow
  }  // end handler
  IL_0076:  ldstr      "Some Sample Name : "
  IL_007b:  ldloca.s   numValue1
  IL_007d:  call       instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
  IL_0082:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string)
  IL_0087:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
  IL_008c:  nop
  IL_008d:  ret
```